# Vector spaces, matrices from $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$

Tags: vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I am not sure what's the answer for this, 
this is the question:
Is

[image]

a vector space?

Or in another format: 
Is it a "mini" vector space (I don't know what it's called in English, but its a vector space which contains another vector space) for the vector space $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}?$

We can start checking that way:

1. Of course it's not an empty group.
2. taking two of the group, adding them together, 
   we get:

[image]

now is what we have in the group? I am not sure because there is 2 instead
of 1 at the place 21...

Would appreciate any help! thanks a lot!

Comment: for this format and the addition, indeed, it doesn't work. But with matrix product and rotations ( by example ) you may build a sub group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This set is not a subspace (I believe this is the word you are looking for) of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$.

The easiest way to see this is to notice that the matrix $0$ cannot be in the set, since for three of the entries to be zero $a$ has to be $0$, but for the bottom left to be $0$, $a$ has to equal $1$.

> I am not sure because there is 2 instead of 1 at the place (2,1)

This also shows that the sum is not in the set: the new $a$ should be $a_1 + a_2$ but that cannot work for the bottom left entry for the reason you say.